# New standup of WSO2 Identity Server, changing user store to MariaDB, missing several tables

Tags: mysql, wso2, mariadb

WSO2 Identity Server 5.6
Red Hat 7.5
MariaDB - 5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Using included MySQL connector

Followed official documentation on changing user store from H2 embedded to MySQL/MariaDB.
Ran both the mysql5.7.sql script found in IS_HOME/dbscripts and the mysql-5.7.sql found in IS_HOME/debscripts/identity

IS starts and seems to connect to the MariaDB user store, however, the log is throwing several JAVA excepts all related to missing tables that are in fact missing:

```
Table 'regdb.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT' doesn't exist
Table 'regdb.IDN_CLAIM' doesn't exist
Table 'regdb.IDN_SCIM_GROUP' doesn't exist
Table 'regdb.WF_BPS_PROFILE' doesn't exist
Table 'regdb.IDP' doesn't exist
```

I am about to open up the .sql files and compare, but the documentation is somewhat vague, and I am reading mixed solutions here.  Would just like a current .sql file which creates the correct tables for IS 5.6 in a newly created regdb database.

Thanks for everyone's time.

master-datasources.xml

```
<providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>

    <datasources>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb</url>
                    <username>regadmin</username>
                    <password>regadmin</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix registry database with identity database. Create a separate database for identity tables and refer it from master-datasources.xml. Refer same jndiConfig from identity.xml. If you still have confusion please post master-datasources.xml and identity.xml.

Comment: I initially just followed the instructions in the official documentation here:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Setting+up+MySQL

Comment: Sorry, could not finish post.  Once the official documents did not work, had to check other sources so it is possible I imported tables for other databases.

Comment: I added the requested master-datasources.xml file.  I made no changes to the identity.xml file so it is simply stock.

Answer (score 0):

All the missing tables you have mentioned are included in IS_5.6.0_HOME/dbscripts/identity/mysql.sql. Please verify that you have imported the script correctly.

If you want to move the entire Carbon DB,

- Create a new database (no need to import)
- Update master-datasources.xml as you have done already
- Create database tables automatically by using the -Dsetup parameter on server startup for the first time (wso2server.sh -Dsetup)

Note: If you are populating MySQL 5.7 or later with the -Dsetup command, rename all mysql5.7.sql files in dbscripts/ to mysql.sql.

If you want to move only the user store DB

- Add new data source to the master-datasources.xml instead of updating the carbonDB
- Modify "dataSource" property from user-mgt.xml to the new data source

Read more on separating databases and clustering,
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Setting+Up+Separate+Databases+for+Clustering
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Sharing+Databases+in+a+Cluster